# How to Use Subquery to query Student score?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a new to SQL Server, I have some question to ask. I have table like below:

```
NAME   GRADE    SUBJECT 
JOHN    A       MATH
JOHN    C       PHYSIC
JENNY   B       PHYSIC
JENNY   C       MATH
KENNY   A       MATH
KENNY   B       PHYSIC
```

.....

I want to query to

```
NAME  MATH    PHYSIC
JOHN    A       C
JENNY   C       B
KENNY   A       B
```

Any one help me please!
Thanks

Comment: I believe that the PIVOT relational operator will work in this case, although I do not have a lot of experience implementing it myself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 5):

In case not all names have grades for all subjects

```
SELECT
   b.name, m.grade AS MATH, p.grade AS PHYSIC
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT name FROM MyTable
    ) b
    LEFT JOIN
    MyTable m ON b.name = m.name AND m.subject = "MATH"
    LEFT JOIN
    MyTable p ON b.name = p.name AND p.subject = "PHYSIC"
```

Comment: Thanks all but If I have more subject like school scoreboard and I have subject table join to score table by subject_id how I can query?

Comment: @aliasosx;: that would be a new question. And with more information

Answer (score 4):

You can use PIVOT (since SQL server 2005):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Name, Subject, Grade FROM Grades) o
PIVOT(MAX(Grade) FOR Subject IN ([Math], [Physic])) p
```

Inside PIVOT() operator you have to define an aggregate function, if every person can have one grade for a subject, then MAX() or MIN() is perfect.

Comment: Thanks tpolyak how can we can change aggregate function in PIVOT() to supply Grade value String?

Comment: @aliasosx MAX() and MIN() functions support strings, too

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT t.name, q1.grade AS Math, q2.grade AS Physic
  (SELECT grade FROM your_table t1
  WHERE t.name = t1.name 
    AND t1.subject = "MATH") q1,
  (SELECT grade FROM your_table t2
  WHERE t.name = t2.name 
    AND t2.subject = "PHYSIC") q2
FROM your_table t
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Subqueries may be less efficient than just joining the table twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all records for one subject and join with the same table for the records for the other subject:

```
select
  m.NAME,
  m.GRADE as MATH,
  p.GRADE as PHYSIC
from
  thetable m
  inner join thetable p on p.NAME = m.NAME and p.SUBJECT = 'PHYSIC'
where
  m.SUBJECT = 'MATH'
```

Comment: And if they don't you can change the `inner join` to a `left outer join` or use a pivot table as per my or tpolyak answers.

Answer (score 0):

An example using PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @Students TABLE 
(
    name varchar(10), 
    grade char(1), 
    [subject] varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO @Students VALUES ('JOHN', 'A', 'MATH');
INSERT INTO @Students VALUES ('JOHN', 'C', 'PHYSIC');
INSERT INTO @Students VALUES ('JENNY', 'B', 'PHYSIC');
INSERT INTO @Students VALUES ('JENNY', 'C', 'MATH');
INSERT INTO @Students VALUES ('KENNY', 'A', 'MATH');
INSERT INTO @Students VALUES ('KENNY', 'B', 'PHYSIC');

SELECT *
FROM @Students AS Students
PIVOT 
( 
    MAX(Grade)
    FOR [subject] IN ([MATH], [PHYSIC])
) AS StudentGrades
```

Comment: Thanks Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ. I can Change "IN ([Maths], [Physics])" with subquery? like "IN (select subject from subject_table)"

Comment: No. You would have to construct the query dynamically, as per this article: [Pivots with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2005](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)